# Select all elements that are not descendents of elements with a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to come up with a selector that will select all `textarea` elements, except those that are descendents of the `.noSpell` class.

So I want this to match:

```
<div>
   <textarea />
</div>
```

but not this

```
<div class="noSpell">
   <div>
      <textarea />
   </div>
</div>
```

I tried this:

```
$(":not(.noSpell) textarea")
```

but it didn't work, presumably because while it won't match the outer element, it can match any of the inner ones.

So, how would I write a selector that excludes parts of the DOM tree based on a class name?

Comment: Try using some valid HTML: `<textarea>&nbsp;</textarea>`

Comment: `<textarea />` is valid XHTML (not HTML-compatible, but valid). Stuffing a non-breaking space inside it is probably not a good idea though.

Comment: Damnit, I always add those stupid nbsps! Excuse the error. OP never specified whether it was HTML or XHTML. In HTML, this would break and you'd end up seeing "</div>" inside the textarea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
$("textarea").not(".noSpell textarea")
```

All textareas, then remove the ones that have a parent of `.noSpell`.

Comment: You could selectorize it as `textarea:not(.noSpell textarea)`.  Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

The following works for me:

```
$("textarea").not(".noSpell");
```

Tested in firefox/firebug.

Comment: That would exclude textareas that are members of the class noSpell, not textareas that are descendants of divs that are members of that class. [Tested here](http://jsfiddle.net/YFpbA/)

Comment: Ah I see, I needed to add "textarea" inside the not, whoops

Answer (score -1):

@cdmckay Your method is also right.

Try creating textarea as:

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

and see if your code works.

You might want to do this to see if your code works

```
if($(":not(.noSpell) textarea").length > 0) {
    alert("there");
}
else {
    alert("not there");
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: That won't work, since that will match textareas unless *all* their ancestors are members of the noSpell class (i.e. the parent, the grandparent, and so on until you get the body element and the html element).