# Add class to <code> tag if it's not inside a <pre> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the Highlight.js script in my DocPad website.

I want to apply some nice styles to a simple `<code>` tag (which is what `` in Markdown does), but if I do this then I'm breaking the styles that Highlight.js is using.

However Highlight.js' styles are inside a `<pre>` tag.

So solution? Add a class to the `<code>` tags that aren't inside a `<pre>` tag.

Could you please provide a hint or a general direction of what I need to do to accomplish this? Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: @JohnConde I haven't tried anything yet. I'm still a newbie with jQuery but I'm very aware of what's possible with it. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select all elements that are not descendents of elements with a certain class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208165/select-all-elements-that-are-not-descendents-of-elements-with-a-certain-class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Target all `code` tags that does not have a ancestor `pre` tag :

```
$('code').filter(function() {
    return !$(this).closest('pre').length;
}).css('color', 'red');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/M4RVn/)

Comment: @Jan: Note though that this would delegate the element selection to Sizzle and not a native browser method. `pre code` is not a "simple selector" and not supported by the CSS `:not` selector (and thus not supported by `querySelectorAll`).

Comment: @FelixKling `:not` is a native selector in CSS3. `:has` isn't.

Comment: Excellent adeneo, works perfectly. :) @JanDvorak could you put your code in an answer so that I can upvote it? :)

Comment: @Jan: Maybe I should have made my comment more clear: The native CSS `:not` selector only works with *simple selectors*, but `pre code` is not a simple selector (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation, http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn). Hence `:not(pre code)` cannot be resolved with `querySelectorAll` and has to be handled by Sizzle.

Comment: @FelixKling ah, thanks. Didn't know there was such limitation.